# SQL-Teradata: How to create a new column composed of a formula

Tags: sql, teradata

```
    cust_id acct_id trxn_amt    trxn_cnt
 1  66685638    10,028,717,398  199.75  5
 2  66685638    10,028,849,377  76.16   2
```

Say I have a table of customers with multiple account IDs and I want to create a new column for  that's the summation of all of the transaction amounts for each customer (199.75+76.16 for cust_id=66685638) as well as another column thats the % of total spend for each account (for first account its 199.75/(76.15+199.75)). Each customer may have anywhere from 2-4 acct_ids.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Your question does not demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
select cust_id, 
       sum(trxn_amt) as total_amount,
       trxn_amt / sum(trxn_amt) as pct
from customers
group by cust_id
order by cust_id;
```

or if you want to see each individual row from the customers table:

```
select cust_id, 
       acct_id,
       trxn_amt, 
       sum(trxn_amt) as over (partition by cust_id) as total_amount,
       trxn_amt / sum(trxn_amt) as over (partition by cust_id) as pct
from customers
order by cust_id;
```